# How do I implement an SVN hook to know the filename of the file committed, etc.?

Tags: svn, windows-xp, tortoisesvn, hook, post-commit

I am using Windows XP and TortoiseSVN, and I would like to know the filename, the path of the file, author, and other details about the revision committed to the repository by using a post-commit hook. Do we have to use a certain language to do this such as Python or is this possible to write even by using a batch file only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice tutorial on how to create SVN hooks http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook
Basically you need to create a post-commit.exe or bat script. It can execute a python code of you want py calling:

python myhook.py

Inside the script.

Answer (score 1):

Start [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks)

Quote from that link:

> Windows, however, uses file extensions to determine whether a program is executable, so you would need to supply a program whose basename is the name of the hook and whose extension is one of the special extensions recognized by Windows for executable programs, such as *.exe* for programs and *.bat* for batch files.